# Vertically aligning author names in IEEEtran

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, ieeetran, author

I am working on an IEEE paper with 6 author, but Latex does not vertically align the names well:

[image]

How can I make sure the author names are vertically aligned better?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\begin{document}


\title{Title of the Paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Emil Rijcken}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Jheronimus Academy of Data Science} \\
\textit{Eindhoven University of Technology}\\
Eindhoven, The Netherlands \\
e.f.g.rijcken@tue.nl}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
}
    
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{abstract}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working exemple adapted from your code (I have removed what is not relevent):

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the Paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Emil Rijcken}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Jheronimus Academy of Data Science} \\
\textit{Eindhoven University of Technology}\\
Eindhoven, The Netherlands \\
e.f.g.rijcken@tue.nl}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Abcd Efghijk}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Jheronimus Academy of Data Science} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Eindhoven, The Netherlands\\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Department} \\
\textit{University}\\
Location \\
email address}
}

\maketitle
    
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
\end{abstract}

\section{title}
\end{document}
```

and you obtain this:

[image]

Which is not so very beautiful.

The [manual of the `IEEEtran` class](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran_HOWTO.pdf) says this (see section IV B 2, page 5):

> If there are more than three authors and/or the text is too wide to fit across the page, use an alternate long format

and gives an example. Here I adapted it to your code:

```latex
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}

\title{Title of the Paper}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1},
Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, James K irk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3},
Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} and Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}} 
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, Georgia 30 332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco,
California 96678-2391\\ Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212} 
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc.,
123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, California 90210--4321}}  
   
\maketitle
    
\begin{abstract}
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum.
\end{abstract}

\section{title}
\end{document}
```

which gives this style of layout:

[image]

So with more than three authors, use the latter layout.